# Has $\ 2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{41}+1\mod n\ $ a solution?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Has $$2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{41}+1\mod n$$ a solution with a positive integer $\ n>1\ $ ?

Motivation : The equation $$2^{n-1}\equiv k\mod n$$ has always a solution, if $\ k-1\ $ has an odd prime factor (this odd prime factor is then a solution) and for $\ k=2^m+1\ $ , I know a solution for $$m=1,2,3,\cdots,40$$ Hence, this is the smallest number for which I know no solution. Upto $\ n=10^9\ $, there is no solution.

Comment: Could you please say something more about the cases $m<41$? How did you find solutions in those cases?

Comment: Do you know $n$ modulo $3$ or $4$? Can you rule out the case $11\mid n$?

Comment: n is odd. not prime. etc.

Comment: it's also not 0 mod 3.

Comment: I have done some computations, and off they are correct, there is no solution with $n<10^{10}$. Out of curiosity, what are solutions for $m=2$ and $m=12$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I found the solutions only by an improved brute-force version. The smallest solution for $k=5$, for example is $$n=24430928839$$

Comment: First restriction : Since $n$ must be odd and therefore $n-1$ even, every prime factor $p$ of a solution $n$ of $$2^{n-1}\equiv k\mod n$$ with odd $k$ must have the property that $k$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$. Second restriction : A prime $p$ can only be a prime factor of a solution $n$, if $2^s\equiv k\mod p$ has a solution. In this case, the solutions $s$ are unique modulo the order of $2$ modulo $p$. This accelerates the search, but for small primes is still time-consuming. Very nice would be a method to construct a solution.

Comment: For $m=12$, a solution is $$n=45338810593$$

Comment: If these solutions represent some interest, I'd suggest to add the minimal solutions (indexed by $m$) as a sequence to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org). There are many other sequences of similar kind already present there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, $n=24189255799819$ is a solution (may be not the smallest one). Tried to search for $n=pq$ with $p,q$ prime and $p$ small, by factoring $2^p-2k$, and got it already at $p=11$.